# how to pass argument in twisted decorator defer.inlineCallbacks?

Tags: python, twisted

i want to pass url into task function, in order to use get different site content at one time.
But it looks like it can't run completed. It will stop unexcepted.

```
    from scrapy.selector import Selector

def get_response_callback(content):
    txt = str(content,encoding='utf-8')
    resp = Selector(text=txt)
    title = resp.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first()
    print(title)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def task(*args,**kwargs):
    # url = 'http://www.baidu.com'
    url=kwargs.get('url')
    print(url)
    d=getPage(url.encode('utf-8'))
    d.addCallback(get_response_callback)
    yield d

def done(*args,**kwargs):
    reactor.stop()

task_list = []
url_list = ['http://www.baidu.com','http://www.bing.com','http://www.qq.com']
for i in url_list:
    d=task(url=i)
    task_list.append(d)

dd = defer.DeferredList(task_list)

dd.addBoth(done) # should use done1 to avoid not stoping the function

reactor.run()
```

How can i pass argument to task function ?

Comment: It looks like you found a way, though not a great way, to do this.  You should just define a url parameter to `task`.  `inlineCallbacks` doesn't really affect this.  So it's not clear what problem you're really having is.  What error are you encountering?  Include it in the question.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone when i run above code, it has exception :http://www.baidu.com
http://www.bing.com
http://www.qq.com
Unhandled error in Deferred:                   if i have ten url to pass to the task and generate 10 defer, but actually it only run 2~2 defer then return Unhandled error.